# How to reduce CPU usage when scanning for folders/sub-folders/files?

Tags: delphi

I have developed an application that scans basically everywhere for a file or list of files. 
When I scan small folders like 10 000 files and sub files there is no problem. But when I scan for instance my entire users folder with more than 100 000 items, it is very heavy on my processor. It takes about 40% of my processor's power.

Is there a way to optimize this code so that it uses less CPU?

```
procedure GetAllSubFolders(sPath: String);
var
  Path: String;
  Rec: TSearchRec;
begin
  try
    Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPath);
    if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, Rec) = 0 then
      try
        repeat
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          if (Rec.Name <> '.') and (Rec.Name <> '..') then
          begin
            if (ExtractFileExt(Path + Rec.Name) <> '') And
              (ExtractFileExt(Path + Rec.Name).ToLower <> '.lnk') And
              (Directoryexists(Path + Rec.Name + '\') = False) then
            begin
              if (Pos(Path + Rec.Name, main.Memo1.Lines.Text) = 0) then
              begin
                main.ListBox1.Items.Add(Path + Rec.Name);
                main.Memo1.Lines.Add(Path + Rec.Name)
              end;
            end;

            GetAllSubFolders(Path + Rec.Name);
          end;
        until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
      finally
        FindClose(Rec);
      end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

My app searches for all the files in a selected folder and sub-folder, zip's them and copies them to another location you specify.

The `Application.ProcessMessages` command is there to make sure the application doesn't look like it is hanging and the user closes it. Because finding 100 000 files for instance can take an hour or so...

I am concerned about the processor usage, The memory is not really affected.

Note: The memo is to make sure the same files are not selected twice.

Comment: Are you concerned about CPU usage or memory usage?

Comment: Warning: a "Application.ProcessMessages" downvote is waiting just around the corner ;)

Comment: What is your program actually trying to do? Personally I expect that the call to ProcessMessages is bad for performance. Right in the innermost loop, that is going to sting like heck. You really need this code in a thread with batched updates to the UI, and a virtual list view. I guess. Maybe.  But since we still don't know what the problem is, it's hard to prescribe a solution.

Comment: @mjn Why a downvote for it?

Comment: Im sorry guys, kind of new to all this. Does it make sense now?

Comment: In your delphi IDE, press ctrl-D to autoformat your source code. Paste it into the SO editor, mark it and press ctrl-K.

Comment: Long-running tasks should not run in the main (UI) thread, but in a background worker thread. The need for Application.ProcessMessages to keep the application responsive is an indicator of a strong coupling of the task with the user interface.

Comment: @lurd thank you, i was not aware of this option. i manually do it usually and it is a real drag.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is zip a folder (and its contents) you don't need to traverse the directory structure at all.  You only need to add the folder to a zip archive and zip it.  There are many ways to do this - which version of Delphi are you using?  What versions of Windows do you want support for?  Unless you mean to say that your application is *individually* zipping each file (which seems extremely silly).

Comment: BTW Won't this code result in dupes when there are symbolic links and he just matches Path+Rec.Name?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see the following performance problems:

1. The call to `Application.ProcessMessages` is somewhat expensive. You are polling for messages rather than using a blocking wait, i.e. `GetMessage`. As well as the performance issue, the use of `Application.ProcessMessages` is generally an indication of poor design for various reasons and one should, in general, avoid the need to call it.
2. A non-virtual list box performs badly with a lot of files.
3. Using a memo control (a GUI control) to store a list of strings is exceptionally expensive.
4. Every time you add to the GUI controls they update and refresh which is very expensive.
5. The evaluation of `Memo1.Lines.Text` is extraordinarily expensive.
6. The use of `Pos` is likewise massively expensive.
7. The use of `DirectoryExists` is expensive and spurious. The attributes returned in the search record contain that information.

I would make the following changes:

- Move the search code into a thread to avoid the need for `ProcessMessages`. You'll need to devise some way to transport the information back to the main thread for display in the GUI.
- Use a virtual list view to display the files.
- Store the list of files that you wish to search for duplicates in a dictionary which gives you `O(1)` lookup. Take care with case-insensitivity of file names, an issue that you have perhaps neglected so far. This replaces the memo.
- Check whether an item is a directory by using `Rec.Attr`. That is check that `Rec.Attr and faDirectory <> 0`.

Comment: Thank you david for the info. I did not realize that i made so many mistakes regarding this. I am not familiar with thread usage or the usage of virtual list, Further more i am not sure what you mean by `duplicates in a dictionary`. Do you have links that can explain more or less how i can implement these?

Comment: There's quite a lot there. Three separate topics, all quite sizeable. Not really suited to be covered in detail in a single answer. Hence my rather high level conceptual answer.

Comment: If you want to move in small steps, replace the memo with a dictionary first. That would be my guess as the quickest way to get some speed up. Then move on to the next problem. And so on.

Comment: How do you implement a dictionary? I am very new to this method of doing things. SO if you can include as much detail as possible i would really appreciate it.

Comment: `uses Generics.Collections; ... var dict: TDictionary<string, Boolean>`. The `Boolean` is a bit pointless, but there's no hash set class, so we can use a dictionary instead.

Comment: @Marcel  Your opening question is already very broad and contains within it a large number of individual questions.  It is not reasonably to expect a private tutorial on all of these topics here.  Stack Overflow works on the principle of one question->one answer.  This segregates topics into individual problems that can continue to have broad utility to many people.  It is not about getting complete solutions to your specific problems.  The correct thing to do is as David suggests - choose one of these and go work on it.  If and when you get stuck, ask a new, specific, question on that topic.

Comment: @Marcel - Note that implementing these changes is very unlikely to reduce CPU usage, if anything, it may increase due to increased efficiency of the code. In that regard your question is probably very poorly asked. For example, one answer to your actual question could be to suggest inserting 'Sleep's after 'ProcessMessages', then you watch CPU usage going down and processing taking till infinity..

Comment: Then again, CPU usage may actually decrease if the code becomes fast enough for the bottleneck to become I/O bound, which is very likely - thinking about it again.

Comment: @Sertac yes, this should absolutely be io bound

Comment: Points 3) and 4) - I learned this the hard way.  Eventually. To this day, I cannot believe just how incredibly slow Windows GUI calls can be.

Comment: @Marcel maybe you _should_ try to implement threading. It is not _that_ difficult if you do not want to interact with your threads (i.e. by accessing shared resources) and it highly increases the quality of your code. In that case you would pass a `TStringList` to your thread which fills it with the results then sends a windows message to your form when it is finished. Then you could use your TStringList to be displayed. It would also force you to separate _"business logic"_ from GUI which is a big plus.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer which says you would do best to do what you're doing in a background thread and I don't want to encourage you to persist in doing it in your main thread.

However, if you go to a command prompt and do this:

```
dir c:\*.* /s > dump.txt & notepad dump.txt
```

you may be surprised quite how quickly Notepad pops into view.

So there are few things you could do to speed up your GetAllSubFolders, even if you keep it in your main thread, e.g. to bracket the code by calls to main.Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate and main.Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate, likewise main.Listbox1.Items.BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.  This will stop these controls being updated while it executes (which is actually what your code is spending most of its time doing, that and the "if Pos( ...)" business I've commented on below).  And, if you haven't gathered already, Application.ProcessMessages is evil (mostly).

I did some timings on my D: drive, which is a 500Gb SSD with 263562 files in 35949 directories.

1. The code in your q: 6777 secs
2. Doing a dir to Notepad as per the above: 15 secs
3. The code below, in main thread: 9.7 secs

The reason I've included the code below in this answer is that you'll find it much easier to execute in a thread because it gathers the results into a TStringlist, whose contents you can then assign to your memo and listbox once the thread has completed.

A few comments on the code in your q, which I imagine you might have got from somewhere.

- It pointlessly recurses even when the current entry in Rec is a plain file.  The code below only recurses if the current Rec entry is a directory.
- It apparently tries to avoid duplicates by the "if Pos( ...)" business, which shouldn't be necessary (except maybe if there's a symbolic link (e.g created with the MkLink command) somewhere that points elsewhere on the drive) and does it in a highly inefficient manner, i.e. by searching for the filename in the memo contents - those will get longer and longer as it finds more files).  In the code below, the stringlist is set up to discard duplicates and has its Sorted property set to True, which makes its checking for duplicates much quicker, becauseit can then do a binary search through its contents rather than a serial one.
- It calculates Path + Rec.Name 6 times for each thing it finds, which is avoidably inefficient at r/t and inflates the source code.  This is only a minor point, though, compared to the first two.

Code:

```
function GetAllSubFolders(sPath: String) : TStringList;

  procedure GetAllSubFoldersInner(sPath : String);
  var
    Path,
    AFileName,
    Ext: String;
    Rec: TSearchRec;
    Done: Boolean;
  begin
    Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPath);
    if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, Rec) = 0 then begin
        Done := False;
        while not Done do begin
         if (Rec.Name <> '.') and (Rec.Name <> '..') then begin
            AFileName := Path + Rec.Name;
            Ext := ExtractFileExt(AFileName).ToLower;
           if not ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) then begin
             Result.Add(AFileName)
           end
           else begin
             GetAllSubFoldersInner(AFileName);
           end;
         end;
         Done := FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
        end;
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.BeginUpdate;
  Result.Sorted := True;
  Result.Duplicates := dupIgnore;  // don't add duplicate filenames to the list

  GetAllSubFoldersInner(sPath);
  Result.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  T1,
  T2 : Integer;
  TL : TStringList;
begin
  T1 := GetTickCount;

  TL := GetAllSubfolders('D:\');

  try
    Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Text := TL.Text;
    finally
      Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;

    T2 := GetTickCount;

    Caption := Format('GetAll: %d, Load: %d, Files: %d', [T2 - T1, GetTickCount - T2, TL.Count]);
  finally
    TL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to it.

Comment: I posted an update (I'll delete this comment once you've seen it).

Comment: @MartynA I'm not sure it is a **good practice** to use the `Result` of your function in the embedded procedure directly. I see you _can_ do it, but it produces a _maintenance problem_. I mean imagine if in a refactoring circle years later _Igor the ax murderer maintenance programmer_ wants to turn your embedded procedure into a private method. Or a function with a boolean result. Not to mention it is inconsistent too. I mean if you use `Result` of the parent why don't you use `sPath` too? They are on the same level of abstraction. to be continued...

Comment: @MartynA ...continue. You also _should not instantiate a class in a procedure and release it in an other one_ if you can avoid it. For example it could be avoided in this case by using a procedure with a `TStringList` typed parameter which expects a _preinitialized_ `TStringList`.

Comment: @mg30rg:  Thanks for your interest.  Use of the Result in a local procedure was, imo, preferable to the artifice of the local being instead defined as a function which returns ... what, another stringlist or a string? - bearing in mind that it's likely to be called arbitarily many times (in my case tens of thousands) before the enclosing function is returned.  Anyway it's a fair point for the OP to consider.

Comment: @mg30rg:  Well "should" <> Holy writ.  And I absolutey disagree with your suggested alternative - I deliberately wrote it that way to avoid the OP being tempted to try and populate the q's memo + listbox directly, as might happen if it were written with a TStringlist param, especially as the OP might then be puzzled why one couldn't pass the Memo's Lines property to it without a dodgy cast.  Anyway, I don't see a function which returns a (Delphi) object its result as problematic.  There's just as much risk that the user will neglect to .Free it afterwards as calling an object's constructor.

Comment: @MartynA Well, I wrote _you should have done_ differently not you are _explicitly wrong_. It _can_ be done, it is just not be prefered. My problem with returning a (non-reference-counted) object is that calling the constructor and releasing the instance are in different subroutines, so it visually differs from the usual `instance:=TObject.Create;try;{PerformTasksHere};finally;instance.Free;end;` sequence which IMHO decreases code readability. (But once again it is an **opinion** of mine, not a general rule.)

Comment: @mg30rg:  Sure, about opinions.  I think my bottom line about this kind of thing is that there comes a point when the coder just has to understand what they're doing in terms of housekeeping.  I have a similar attitude to the rule of English grammar that one should not split an infinitive; it's fine to do occasionally, provided you do it emphatically and aware of the rule.

Comment: @MartynA i am going to implement this and test it. I will get back to you asap. Thank you

Comment: Feel free to vote for it if it works for you ;=)  (I mean, if you haven't already).

Comment: @MartynA: Thanks for this code. Just a side note, I tested the speed of it against of an one liner in scala, and on a local folder I have, with subfolders and about 50k files in total. The Delphi app takes 1 s to scan folder and subfolders while the scala version takes 7s. I also did it with a Java code which takes around 6s. I found it very interesting the difference in performance. Delphi beats them all. I didn't try C# but I wouldn't be surprised if it has a performance similar to Java.

Comment: @costa:  I'm glad you've found it helpful.  Regarding the timings relative to the others you tried, my Delphi implementation doesn't contain any particular optimisations, so I dare say someone who is interested could improve it quite easily.  That's all part of the fun of Delphi, you aren't just stuck with what some library function provides ;=)