# getting count of folders inside specified directory(subdirectories too included)

Tags: delphi

I have procedure which gives me folders  of current directory only.How to get all folders in  subdirectories also(all the folders present in current directory + all the folders present in subdirectorie) Thanks in advance

```
procedure GetSubDirectories(const directory : string; list : TStrings) ;
var
 sr : TSearchRec; 
begin  
 try     
  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) < 0 then
   Exit
  else
  repeat
  if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) AND (sr.Name <> '.') AND (sr.Name <> '..')) then
   List.Add(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + sr.Name) ;
  until
   FindNext(sr) <> 0;
  finally
   SysUtils.FindClose(sr) ;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce CPU usage when scanning for folders/sub-folders/files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301936/how-to-reduce-cpu-usage-when-scanning-for-folders-sub-folders-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
program Project9;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function ListFolders(const DirName: string): Integer;
var
  Path: string;
  F: TSearchRec;
  SubDirName: string;

begin
  Path:= DirName + '\*.*';
  Result:= 0;
  if FindFirst(Path, faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            SubDirName:= IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DirName) + F.Name;
            Writeln(SubDirName);
            Result:= Result + 1 + ListFolders(SubDirName);
          end;
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  Writeln(ListFolders('C:\Temp'));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working correctly. Can i get borth counts in one function? Like passing one more parameter as subdir as boolean?

Comment: sure you can; why not to do the rest yourself?

Comment: Can you give me hint just where to put condition?

Answer (score 0):

function GetCount(Dir : string):Integer;`{
 user these in your use list
 System.Ioutils
}` 
    begin
     Result := Length(TDirectory.GetFiles(dir,'*.*',TsearchOption.soAllDirectories))
    end;

Comment: Add additional details to the answer.

Comment: It returns 0 if in specified Dir is another Dir and then files